# Rails 3/jquery - Tabs rendering partials using ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Using Rails 3 and jquery, I'm trying to setup a simple 3 tab navigation for my post#show page, rendering _post _comments and _related partials into the view when clicked.

These partials don't have their own controller actions, currently.

What would be the cleanest Rails way to handle these ajax calls?

I tried this but it's not working:

Post controller:

```
def tab  
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Post show view:

```
<%= link_to "Comments", {:action => 'tab'}, :remote => true %>
```

/views/posts/tab.js.erb

```
$('#postshow').html("<%= escape_javascript(render('comments')) %>");
```

However, if I do this, when I try to open my Track Show page i get hungup with this error 
"No route matches {:action=>"tab", :controller=>"posts"}"

i thought i defined an action for tab that should render the tab.js.erb...  But more importantly this seems a little clunky to just switch around between three partials.

Any help is much appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it.  Just needed to add the resource to routes.rb... thought that part just magically happened.

put this in routes.rb

```
resources :posts do
  ...
  member do
    get 'tab'
  end
end
```

and now it finds the route and renders the javascript.

having said that, if anyone reads this post and can point out a way cleaner or simpler way to set up ajax links for rendered partials, that would be super sweet.

Answer (score 1):

Your action lies in PostsController, so you should write:

```
<%= link_to "Comments", {:controller => "posts", :action => "tab"}, :remote => true %>
```

Comment: My bad, I actually just copied that code wrong, just fixed it in my post.  I am using the posts controller and the error says `No route matches {:controller=>"posts", :action=>"tab"}`.  I did try putting `:controller => "posts"` into the link_to block and it didn't help.  I'm sure I'm doing plenty wrong here but why would it say `no route matches` when I definitely do have a tab route in posts controller?  that confuses me.

Comment: Then you have some problem in routes.rb. Can you post the line from this file here?